# HashMap get performance with simple and complex key

Tags: java

I want a map whose get operation is as fast as possible.
The key is set of string (2 table names in database which are related) and value is a integer (the number is id of row in database which has actual relationship between tables),

example :

```
table 1 - employee
table 2 - company
relationship - employee.comp_id = company.id
```

I have no intentions to read keys in the map. I just want the relationship id for the given 2 table names. so I wrote a small program to test get operation in HashMap.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    int limit = 1000;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>(1000 * 1000);
    HashMap<Set<String>, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<>(1000 * 1000);
    String k1, k2;
    Set<String> k3;
    Integer k4;
    for (int x = 0; x < limit; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < limit; y++) {
            k1 = String.valueOf(x);
            k2 = String.valueOf(y);
            k3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(k1, k2));
            k4 = k3.hashCode();
            m2.put(k3, k4);
            m1.put(k4, k4);
        }
    }

    long t1, t2;
    System.out.println("init");

    t1 = System.nanoTime();
    // block 1 /////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int x = 0; x < limit; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < limit; y++) {
            m1.get(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(x),
                String.valueOf(y))).hashCode());
        }
    }
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    t2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(t2 - t1);
    t1 = t2;
    // block 2 /////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int x = 0; x < limit; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < limit; y++) {
            m2.get(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(x),
                String.valueOf(y))));
        }
    }
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    t2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(t2 - t1);
}
```

**On my machine block 2 takes approximately 9 times more time than block 1 to complete execution.**

Is the performance dependent on complexity of the Object used as key.
in either case I know hashcode is calculated by the impementation of HasMap.get() method.

Actually for code in block 1 hashcode is calculated by my code as well as implementation of HashMap, but still the performance is better than block 2 where hashcode of the Set is computed only by implementation of HashMap.

notice that Set is being created in both blocks

Comment: This was good learning. I thought the performance can be improved by using simple keys instead of complex one, but later I spent some time to see if the two hash maps used in experiment can serve the intended purpose. after addition of key value pairs to these map, the map with integer key had less key value pairs than the one which has Set<String> as key. some keys were overwritten in Map<Integer, Integer> so it means some relationships were lost in the process. I conclude that trying to optimize things this way can result in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of `get()` depends on two things:

- The performance of the parameter key objects `hashCode()` method
- The performance of the existent key objects `equals()` method

Take a look at the [documentation of `HashMap.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29). A map contains key value pairs. To find the right value for a key, the `equals()` method of the key is used. In a `HashMap`, the number of keys to compare is reduced by using it's hash. So `hashCode()` is executed exactly once on the key object you pass as a parameter.

The implementation of `HashMap` then has a couple of possible key objects it has to compare (ideally only one). This means that it has to execute `equals()` 1 to n times.

If you have a `Set` as key type, both are more complex, since they iterate over all objects contained in the `Set` itself. Take a look of the implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `HashSet` and compare it to the ones of `String`.

As for your example: Since `hashCode()` is executed exactly once it has less impact than `equals()`. In your first block you compute it once for `HashSet` and then `get()` does it once again for `Integer` (which isn't really that complex). This doesn't make a lot difference in the `hashCode()` part. The first block is a lot faster because `equals()` is executed for `Integer` instead of `HashSet`, which is a lot faster.

Comment: The explanation in last block is convincing, I will verify it later. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you are trying to do with this code, but as to your question, when the key of the `HashMap` is a `Collection` (as in your `HashMap<Set<String>, Integer>`), the `hashCode` calculation requires iteration over all the elements contained in the `Collection`, so it would take more time than calculating a `hashCode` that depends on a constant number of properties.

Comment: The code is just a random experiment that I did. iteration over collection to compute hashcode happens even in block 1 when I call hashCode() method on a new Set.