# Enums VS Objects

Tags: java, oop, enums, hashmap

I am creating a "mock-dictionary" using a HashMap with the keys being the word the user wants to search, such as "dog" or "bike". And the second value, in simple terms, is the definition. The definition will also be further broken down into different definitions for each applicable part of speech (i.e, verb/noun/adj).
However, I am wondering what the performance differences are between doing something like HashMap<ENUM_Name, Enum_GetterMethod> vs HashMap<Object.getName, Object.getDefinitionMethod>.

Basically, I am confused about why we need ENUMS when we have objects, and when it is better to use an ENUM over an object and vise versa. I have read other forums about how Enums are cleaner and are great for readability, but I don't see anything as to when to create an Enum class vs just use objects?

*code is just as an example:*

```
class Dictionary{

  public enum Words{ 
     Dog("noun definition"),
     Bike("noun definition", "verb definiton");

     //constructors & private variables & getter methods
  }

  private static void Main() {

    //use a for() loop to add in all the keys/values to map
    HashMap<ENUM_Name, Enum_GetterMethod> 
  }
}
```

VS

```
class DictionaryWords{

  //private variables for defintions
  //constructors for objects
  //getter methods for private variables

  public static void main(){
 
    Dictionary Dog = new Dictionary("noun definition");
    Dictionary Bike = new Dictionary("noun definition", "verb definiton");

    //use a for() loop to add in all the keys/values to map
    HashMap<Object_Name, Object_GetterMethod> 

}
```

Comment: `enum`s make sense when you have things that are *enumerable*, like the possible states of a procedure, for example. Not the entries of a dictionary, for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Enums are a great option for a small, fixed set of related object instances.

1. Small, because you have to list each and every one inside a single class file.
2. Fixed, because enums are not mutable or extensible. They are set at compile time.
3. Related, because ideally you want to develop a shared API around the instances. Java enums can be extremely powerful, because they can implement behavior, unlike other languages in which enums are simply an enumeration of constant values.

Dictionary words don't fit any of these criteria particularly well.

Comment: This was super helpful and simple. Do you have any other links that I could further understand what you mean with #3. ? thanks so much!

Comment: Consider any scenario where an enum implements an interface. The interface is a shared API, and the enum just happens to be one related set of implementations.

Answer (score 2):

In context of using HashMap, both Enum & Object should give similar performance because underlying implementation of HashMap is that get a hashKey & figure out corresponding return value, so once you get the Hash value of Enum or Object, their difference ends.

If you are looking for some significant performance boost, then for enums you can look into [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html), they are designed specially for Enum keys & internally use Arrays to store data, hence provide you the some performance boost. [Refer this for more info](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/difference-between-enummap-and-hashmap-in-java-vs.html#axzz6tuPMPvrS). I'm not sure what size of dictionary you would be dealing with hence the kind of gain you will get from `EnumMap`.

IMO sticking with Object or string as a key will give you better manageability & flexibility with your dictionary. Writing a whole dictionary in Enum sounds tiresome, where as in String keys you can read data from some file & create your dictionary dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are useful when you have a game and you need levels low,medium,high or you have a music player and you need music sound levels low,medium,high it is used like these states and creating an enum easier than object

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with @Ekamjit (+1), to whose answer I add only this: the cost of the access to a value by his key using an `HashMap` is O(1) and this could only get worse if your `hasCode` implementation generates too many times the same value for different keys (things that could rarely happens in case of `String`). I found a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27901000/4210091) that could help you understand my little tip better.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are intended for a predefined (you already know them before the program is started), static (they do not change often or at all), small set of related "items".
Examples are "planets" (Mercury, Venus, Earth, ...) or suits of cards (Hearts, Diamonds, ...). Using enumerations in loops or iterations often looks "clearer" than with an self-defined classes:

```
    enum Planets {Mercury, Venus, Earth};

    for (Planets planet: Planets.values()) {
        // do something with the planet
    }
```

On the other hand, if you want to dynamically grow your dictionary entries (either by having a user enter values or by reading the values from a database), you can't use enums but have to resort to classes as new instances (objects) can be created on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants .

How to use Java Enum
You can use enums when a variable (especially a method parameter) can only take one out of a small set of possible values. Examples would be things like days in a Week(Sunday, Monday etc..), or Directions (NORTH, SOUTH, EAST and WEST).

You can use an enum instead of a class if the class should have a fixed enumerable number of instances.